# My Heatmap on ggplot2 isn't showing part of the data but the data.frame seems to be fine

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying the following method:

```
MAPE <- c(.236, .186, .047, .035, .013, 3.117, 3.092, 3.021, 2.975, 1.616,
          .192,.131, .07, .017, 0, .431, .404, .321, .301, .821,
          .236, .18, .098, .083, .061, 3.117, 3.09, 2.998, 2.955, 2.094,
          .192,.125, .118, .039, .05, .431, .405, .314, .309, .9)
DemandSys <- c("Logit","Logit","Logit","Logit", "Logit",
               "Log-Linear", "Log-Linear","Log-Linear","Log-Linear", "Log-Linear",
               "Linear", "Linear","Linear","Linear","Linear",
               "AIDS", "AIDS", "AIDS", "AIDS", "AIDS")
Method <- rep(c("UPP_no", "UPP_avg", "UPP_est", "Simp", "FOA"), 8)
Eff <- c("both", "both", "both", "both", "both", "both", "both", "both", "both", "both",
         "one", "one", "one", "one", "one","one", "one", "one", "one", "one")
MAPE <- cbind.data.frame(MAPE, Method, Eff, DemandSys)

library(scales)

ggplot(MAPE, aes(x=DemandSys, y=Method, fill=MAPE)) + 
  geom_tile()+ 
  facet_wrap(~ Eff, nrow = 1)
```

However, there seems to be a big chunk of my data that cannot be read into this "heatmap". I keep checking the data.frame and everything seems to be in order. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's because x-axis is not shared between the facets. Try using `facet_wrap(~ Eff, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! is there any reason why you are using `cbind.data.frame`?

Comment: I tried using the "free-x", but the x axis is shared between the facets. I should have all Demand Systems and all methods in "both" and "one".

Comment: Also, I used cbind.data.frame because with just bind my numbers were turning into factors.

Comment: Problem solved. My Eff vector was too short and therefore messed up the data. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My Eff vector was too short and therefore messed up the data. Thank you everyone